# WPF Fill TreeView from Database

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have one problem using TreeView in WPF using the MVVM design pattern.I found a solution that helped me a lot for understanding the principals, but when I applied it in my project, I can't get the desired results. The article is [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/217307/WPF-How-to-Fill-TreeView-from-DataBase).

My base class is:

```csharp
public class ClientTreeViewProducts
{
    public List<ClientTreeViewProducts> Items { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the ViewModel I have a public property that I bind to the `ItemsSource` property of the TreeView:

```
private List<ClientTreeViewProducts> _treeViewSource;
public List<ClientTreeViewProducts> TreeViewSource 
{
    get { return _treeViewSource; }
    set
    {
        if(_treeViewSource!=value)
        {
            _treeViewSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TreeViewSource");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a function that fills the `List`, and it seems to be OK.

And finally here is my xaml that manages the bindings and the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`  :

```xaml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewSource}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helpers:ClientTreeViewProducts}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The problem is when I fill some data in the `TreeViewSource` property, the tree view remains empty (visually). Can someone find what the problem is, because I'm head-banging about this problem for 3 days.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using an `ObservableCollection<ClientTreeViewProducts>` instead of a `List<ClientTreeViewProducts>`? If you add elements to a collection, that collection must implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` to notify the TreeView (or any other ItemsControl).

Comment: Thanks @Sphinxxx , changing to `ObservableCollection<ClientTreeViewProducts>` worked for me, but I'm confused, how come the `DataGrid` works with List<T>, and `TreeView` does not :)

Comment: I suspect it depends when you fill the list with data. If you *first* create a `List<>` and fill it with data, *and then* set `x.TreeViewSource = myFullList;`, the DataGrid (or TreeView) will see that the whole .TreeViewSource changed, and render the items that are already in the list. But the grid/tree still won't change if you add or remove items from that same list later.

Comment: Thanks @Sphinxxx I'll keep this in mind! :)